# How can stop infinite loop in useeffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, frontend

```js
 const [list, setlist] = useState([]);
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/recruiter/postedjobs",requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setlist(data.data);
      });
  });
```

I am working on the react js where i have to show the list of user after the page render so i use the useeffect hook what when i write the useeffect hook it call the api infinite time how  can stop this. if i add the blank dependencies  [] it show requestoptions are missing from dependencies

Comment: Add the `[]` and then either add `requestOptions` to it or put `eslint-disable-next-line` before that line

Comment: What if you add [requestOptions]? It should then re-fetch only if the request options change

Comment: @Teneff `requestOptions` is being recreated each render and is an object that would be subject to a reference comparison. This means that adding `requestOptions` to the dependency array would cause the `useEffect` to run on each re-render.

Comment: i pass the empty array but react shows warning he 'requestOptions' object makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 17) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the initialization of 'requestOptions' in its own useMemo()

Comment: if i add [requestoptions] still the same problem with warning

Comment: I've just noticed, thanks to @JacobSmit, where the request options are defined. Just move the definition outside the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an empty array as a second argument to useEffect Hook.

```
useEffect( ()=>{
      console.log(‘hello’);
   }, [] );
```

If you would leave the second argument of the Effect Hook empty, you would run into an infinite loop because the Effect Hook always runs after the state has changed. Since the Effect Hook triggers another state change, it will run again and again to increase the count.

Comment: it stop the loop but shows the warning React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'requestOptions'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: @Vikas21 It is a warning from eslint, disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You sould pass **requestOptions** as second argument

```
const [list, setlist] = useState([]);
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/recruiter/postedjobs",requestOptions)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setlist(data.data);
          }, [requestOptions]);
      });
```